# Run Go asynchronous operations and write to map

Tags: python, asynchronous, go, google-cloud-platform, goroutine

I have [this project](https://bitbucket.org/codyc54321/golang-w-python/src) that tries to run unlimited bigqueries at the same time in Go. The parent project is all Python. I need to be able to keep track of the query results, like in a map.

```
Input:

{
 'reports_portal': 'select * from reports_portal',
 'billing_portal': 'select * from billing_portal',
}

output:

{
 'reports_portal': [23, 123, 5234, 632],
 'billing_portal': [23, 123, 5234, 632],
}
```

and so on

these bigqueries need to be run asynchronously as they're very slow (from a UI perspective, an SRE waiting 15-30 seconds for results.

I first try to asynchronously write items to a map:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)


func add_to_map(m map[string] string, word string) map[string]string {
    added_word := word + " plus more letters"
    m[word] = added_word
    return m
}


func main() {
    words_map := make(map[string]string)
    words := []string{"giraffe", "cat", "dog", "turtle"}
    for _, this_word := range words {
        go add_to_map(words_map, this_word)
    }
    fmt.Println(words_map)
}
```

blows up like:

```
$ go run try_asynchronous.go 
fatal error: concurrent map writes

goroutine 7 [running]:
runtime.throw(0x10b3b96, 0x15)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:596 +0x95 fp=0xc420032eb8 sp=0xc420032e98
runtime.mapassign(0x109ad20, 0xc420016270, 0xc420032fa0, 0x10b3268)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/runtime/hashmap.go:499 +0x667 fp=0xc420032f58 sp=0xc420032eb8
main.add_to_map(0xc420016270, 0x10b1ba0, 0x3, 0x0)
    /tmp/golang-w-python/try_asynchronous.go:10 +0xa3 fp=0xc420032fc0 sp=0xc420032f58
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2197 +0x1 fp=0xc420032fc8 sp=0xc420032fc0
created by main.main
    /tmp/golang-w-python/try_asynchronous.go:19 +0xc8

goroutine 1 [runnable]:
fmt.(*pp).fmtString(0xc42001e0c0, 0x10b1f52, 0x7, 0x76)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/fmt/print.go:424 +0x1a2
fmt.(*pp).printValue(0xc42001e0c0, 0x10953c0, 0xc42000e260, 0x98, 0x76, 0x1)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/fmt/print.go:729 +0x27aa
fmt.(*pp).printValue(0xc42001e0c0, 0x109ad20, 0xc420016270, 0x15, 0x76, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/fmt/print.go:750 +0x103d
fmt.(*pp).printArg(0xc42001e0c0, 0x109ad20, 0xc420016270, 0x76)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/fmt/print.go:682 +0x217
fmt.(*pp).doPrintln(0xc42001e0c0, 0xc420045f28, 0x1, 0x1)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/fmt/print.go:1138 +0xa1
fmt.Fprintln(0x1108140, 0xc42000c018, 0xc420045f28, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc420045ef0, 0xc420045ee0, 0x1087218)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/fmt/print.go:247 +0x5c
fmt.Println(0xc420045f28, 0x1, 0x1, 0x10b1e6f, 0x6, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/fmt/print.go:257 +0x57
main.main()
    /tmp/golang-w-python/try_asynchronous.go:21 +0x132
exit status 2
```

based on needing to run many queries at once and trying to keep track of the results by their name, I expected to write to a map during asynchronous. But `fatal error: concurrent map writes` says you can't.

I don't understand

1. why not
2. what I should do the run these bigqueries simultaneously.

EDIT:

The closest thing I have, that returns results, is not asynchronous:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var mutex sync.Mutex
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func random_sleep() {
    r := rand.Intn(3000)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(r) * time.Millisecond)
}

func add_to_map(m map[string] string, word string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    added_word := word + " plus more letters"
    mutex.Lock()
    defer mutex.Unlock()
    fmt.Println("Before sleep")
    random_sleep()
    m[word] = added_word
    fmt.Println("Added word %v", word)
}


func main() {
    words_map := make(map[string]string)
    words := []string{"giraffe", "cat", "dog", "turtle"}
    for _, this_word := range words {
        wg.Add(1)
        go add_to_map(words_map, this_word)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(words_map)
}
```

Results are wrong:

```
cchilders:~/work_projects/metricsportal/golang_integration (feature/golang-query) 
$ go run try_async.go 
Before sleep
Added word %v turtle
Before sleep
Added word %v cat
Before sleep
Added word %v giraffe
Before sleep
Added word %v dog
map[dog:dog plus more letters turtle:turtle plus more letters cat:cat plus more letters giraffe:giraffe plus more letters]

cchilders:~/work_projects/metricsportal/golang_integration (feature/golang-query) 
$ go run try_async.go 
Before sleep
Added word %v turtle
Before sleep
Added word %v cat
Before sleep
Added word %v giraffe
Before sleep
Added word %v dog
map[dog:dog plus more letters turtle:turtle plus more letters cat:cat plus more letters giraffe:giraffe plus more letters]
```

Results should be very fast, no longer than 3 seconds (the max of random I think):

```
Expectation - 

Before sleep
Before sleep
Before sleep
Before sleep
Added word %v cat
Added word %v giraffe
Added word %v turtle
Added word %v dog
```

Comment: No types in Go are safe for concurrent writes or reads and writes, you always need synchronization.

Comment: To expand on @JimB 's comment, check out https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action and https://golang.org/pkg/sync/

Comment: sync isnt sufficient, please see notes above. It seems I need channels and the channel has to explictly say "wait". my problem is I don't understand Go greatly and I don't wanna spend all this time and my module not be concurrent. Our biggest issue is trying to multithread well, do I need to use channel?

Comment: Why you call random_sleep() in critical section ? - call it beafore mutex.Lock() because you blocking all threads.

Comment: oh lol ok I'll refactor

Comment: The solutions added are reasonable, however another way you could synchronize the data is by pushing results from all your query routines into a channel and dedicating a single go-routine to updating the map.

Comment: I agree, I had a hunch that's best but never used a channel yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK let me clarify some things and help you.

You don't need to return a modified map from here because your
function gets a reference to map not copy of it. (Let's ignore the fact
that you are completely ignoring return value)

```
func add_to_map(m map[string] string, word string) map[string]string {
    added_word := word + " plus more letters"
    m[word] = added_word
    return m
}
```

Next thing is that you need to synchronize access to map. You can use
[mutex](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex) for this.

```
import "sync"

var mutex sync.Mutex //glabal variable but can be created as local also

func add_to_map(m map[string] string, word string) {
    added_word := word + " plus more letters"
    // here you can do long to compute task and calculate result
    // calc here
    mutex.Lock() //result ready lock mutex
    defer mutex.Unlock() // unlock mutex when we return from function
    m[word] = added_word // result write to shared map
}
```

Note that in Go 1.9 there will be a [Concurrent Map](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.9#sync-map) type.

**Edit**:
You need to wait for all go-routines to finish because your `main()` now finishes before them. You can do this by using [WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var mutex sync.Mutex
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func add_to_map(m map[string] string, word string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    added_word := word + " plus more letters"
    // do heavy work here
    //
    mutex.Lock()
    defer mutex.Unlock()
    m[word] = added_word
}


func main() {
    words_map := make(map[string]string)
    words := []string{"giraffe", "cat", "dog", "turtle"}
    for _, this_word := range words {
        wg.Add(1)
        go add_to_map(words_map, this_word)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(words_map)
}
```

Comment: Fixed have look at Edit section

Comment: Ok I see you used defer, let me try this one

Comment: I tried; if you run my sample above you'll see this does not run concurrently (fire off all 4 actions at once, then add results to map as each result comes in). This won't help speed up our bigqueries, as the slowness is due to waiting for each query to run and return response.

Comment: Don' t call sleep in critical section call it beafore it. (I assume sleep simulates time of cumputation). If your comutation are independent of each other it is safe.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different issues in your code:

1) Even if you are always writing to different keys, you can't do that simultaneously without locking the map: https://golang.org/doc/faq#atomic_maps

So, you need to just make sure you get exclusive access to the map when accessing it.

2) You need to finish for all goroutines to finish before printing the map (that's why you get inconsistent results in your edited code)

A simple way to solve both issues based on your example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var mutex sync.Mutex
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func add_to_map(m map[string] string, word string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    added_word := word + " plus more letters"
    mutex.Lock()
    defer mutex.Unlock()
    m[word] = added_word
}


func main() {
    words_map := make(map[string]string)
    words := []string{"giraffe", "cat", "dog", "turtle"}
    for _, this_word := range words {
        wg.Add(1)
        go add_to_map(words_map, this_word)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(words_map)
}
```

Comment: @codyc4321: that's not related to the mutex, but to not waiting for the go routines to finish.. see my edited answer

Comment: While I appreciate it, that still doesn't work. The goal of the module is to fire off all 4 queries at once, then write to the results map once they finish. Written like this, it isn't asynchronous nor faster than what we have in python. I added another note

Comment: @codyc4321: this is indeed async, and the 4 queries will execute in parallel

Comment: @codyc4321: the heavy operations should be done outside of the Lock(), otherwise it will not be async..

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

My usage of fake delay was wrong, the solutions both work. Thank you:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var mutex sync.Mutex
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func random_sleep() {
    r := rand.Intn(3000)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(r) * time.Millisecond)
}


func add_to_map(m map[string] string, word string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    added_word := word + " plus more letters"
    fmt.Println("Before sleep")
    random_sleep()
    mutex.Lock()
    defer mutex.Unlock()
    m[word] = added_word
    fmt.Println("Added word %v", word)
}


func main() {
    words_map := make(map[string]string)
    words := []string{"giraffe", "cat", "dog", "turtle"}
    for _, this_word := range words {
        wg.Add(1)
        go add_to_map(words_map, this_word)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(words_map)
}
```

Result:

```
$ go run try_async.go 
Before sleep
Before sleep
Before sleep
Before sleep
Added word %v dog
Added word %v giraffe
Added word %v cat
Added word %v turtle
map[turtle:turtle plus more letters dog:dog plus more letters giraffe:giraffe plus more letters cat:cat plus more letters]
```